# My laptop screen rotates every few minutes, fix?

Tags: linux

I am currently running Kali Linux on my laptop, and suddenly, after a reboot, my screen rotates at its own will. My current fix is to use `xrandr -o normal`, but I would like to prevent the problem rather than having to fix it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xrandr -o normal will work, but try this:

Go into Menu, System Settings, Display, Rotation and set it so it won't change at all.

Comment: Actually, I tried running monitor-sensor and saw that the accelerometer data I was getting was wrong, so I tried disabling the iio-sensor-proxy but it didnt work, so i disabled the accelerometer as in my case it has no purpose, and so far so good